# R scatter plot with hexadecimal colors

Tags: r, colors, hex, factors

I've got a CSV file with 3 columns, the X values, Y values, and their corresponding hexadecimal (#RRGGBB) values. I've been trying to create a scatter/bubble plot with the insides of the bubbles colored according to the hex values.

```
symbols(year, logtrans, circles=size, inches=0.05, bg=intel2$HexLogClock)
```

intel2$HexLogClock contains the hex values.

Sorry again for the noob question, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or unexpected result?

Comment: The colors seem random. I wrote out the colors myself on a scale from #FF0000 (red) to #FFFF00 (yellow) and the colors that appear are all over the charts. It might be easier to use the heat pallete, but I couldn't figure out how to pick colors based on a third variable.

Comment: It sounds like there may not be a problem at all. Your color values may be sorted, but your year and/or logtrans values may not be at all. So the points may truly be a real mess of colors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your trouble may lie in the hex values not being a character. Make sure they are first. See example below:

```
year <- 1:5
logtrans <- log(year)
size <- rep(15,5)
intel2 <- data.frame(HexLogClock=c("#330000", "#FFFFCC", "#660000", "#FF0000", "#00FF00"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
symbols(year, logtrans, circles=size, inches=0.05, bg=intel2$HexLogClock)
```

Notice the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` code, which you can specify for `read.csv` and other import methods to ensure your character data isn't converted to a factor.

You can do this for your data using:

```
intel2$HexLogClock <- as.character(intel2$HexLogClock)
```

Comment: I believe you have to problem +1  and +1 for Jeff's detective work.

Comment: @TylerRinker I believe that is just and right, and have done so. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I imagine `intel2$HexLogClock` is stored as a `factor`. Confirm this with `class(intel2$HexLogClock)`. In this case, each level of the factor is represented by an integer (which is assigned based on the order of factor level's first occurrences), so your first `HexLogClock` color will be black (1=black), then red, then green, blue, cyan, and so on.

To correct this, you need to convert `intel2$HexLogClock` to a character vector, thusly:

```
intel2$HexLogClock <- as.character(intel2$HexLogClock)
```

after which your command should work as you had expected.

Alternatively:

```
symbols(year, logtrans, circles=size, inches=0.05, 
        bg=as.character(intel2$HexLogClock))
```

Comment: +1 for further information that will be useful to future searchers!

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm misunderstanding, if so let me know but you can just supply the hexadecimal values to `col` as in:

```
barplot(1:3, axes=FALSE, col=c("#330000", "#FFFFCC", "660000"))
```

Comment: How would you do this with the parameters I'm trying to pass it? I'm really new to R and don't fully understand the col parameter. The documentation isn't really that clear. But yes, the colors are stored in that format in a vector the same size as the x and y parameters.