# Produce a scatterplot where the size of a point changes according to a third variable

Tags: r, excel, vba

It is possible to produce a graph within R for the Size of a point to  Represent the Number of Documents per Year. I have tried to produce a graph like this within Excel using a scatter chart but no use.

I know this can be done using a World Map and Map Bubbles in R but it would be very useful if it could be done just a chart with no world map.

I found this code on here [StackOverFlow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238526/r-scatter-plot-with-hexadecimal-colors)

```
year <- 1:5 
logtrans <- log(year) 
size <- rep(15,5) 
intel2 <- data.frame(HexLogClock=c("#330000", "#FFFFCC", "#660000",
                                   "#FF0000", "#00FF00"),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
symbols(year, logtrans, circles=size, inches=0.25, bg=intel2$HexLogClock)
```

I would like to be able to produce this figure, but have the size of the circles to change depending on the value per year.

Cheers,
Jess

Example Data Set (Sorry about the Formatting)

```
Country Year 2008   Year 2009 Year 2010 Year 2011
Argentina   35  60  89  120
Austrailia  56  89  75  100
Canada            25    65  89  148
Ireland 25  65  90  200
Italy             27    75  45  100
New Zealand 56  98  36  54
Spain             78    54  100 89
United Kingdom  56  102 158 238
United States   45  99  179 250
```

I would like to be able to do this using the TXT file above I read the data in using the command!

```
 myData3 <- read.delim(file="noofpublications_Collab2.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?  Without that, the only answer we can give is: "yes, you can do what you're asking."

Comment: Will add an example txt file above :)

Answer (score 2):

```
symbols(year, logtrans, circles=logtrans, inches=0.25, bg=intel2$HexLogClock)
```

usually you'll be working with a data.frame:

```
DF <- data.frame(year, logtrans, color=intel2$HexLogClock)
```

then the call to `symbols` becomes:

```
symbols(DF$year, DF$logtrans, circles=DF$logtrans, inches=0.25, bg=DF$color)
```

This can also be done in one of the more advanced plotting libraries.  My preference is `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x=year, y=logtrans, colour=color, size=logtrans)) + geom_point()\\
```

---

Per the OP's Comment and edit,

Re-creating a portion of the data:

```
dat <- structure(list(country = c("argentina", "australia", "canada", "ireland", "italy"), year08 = c(35, 56, 25, 25, 27), year09 = c(60, 89, 65, 65, 75), year10 = c(89, 75, 89, 90, 45), year11 = c(120, 100, 148, 200, 100)), .Names = c("country", "year08", "year09", "year10", "year11"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would then use `melt` from the `reshape2` package.

```
library(reshape2)
dat.melt <- melt(dat, id.var='country')
```

And then plot with ggplot:

```
ggplot(dat.melt, aes(x=variable, y=value, colour=country, size=value)) + geom_point()
```

In the `aes` I have set the names of the things which control different pieces of my plot.  the dots are colored by country, and sized by the value.  But you can switch this all around if you choose.

However, I have no idea if that is the comparison you're trying to make!

Comment: so using the table that I have included above how would you do this?

Comment: Can the size of the circle be changed? Depending upon the Country or Year as shown above?

Comment: How could the data be imported using a TXT with the data file that I have included as this would be useful as well :)

Comment: @JessSheasby this should probably be another question, or better yet, something you can solve on your own, but you will use `read.table` or `read.csv`.

Comment: For the plot I was hoping to just have one country on the graph not several or have just on year on the graph was the comparrison I was hoping to make :) How would you do this?

Comment: For the data to read in I have used read.delim for my TXT file would it be better to user read.table or read.csv in this case?

Comment: @JessSheasby you can subset the data (`dat.melt[dat.melt$country=='italy',]`); skip the melt step and change the `aes`; or use something like `?facet_wrap`.  As far as the read step, `read.csv` is a wrapper for `read.table` as is `read.delim`.  take a look at `?read.table` to see all your options.

Comment: Ok, so I now know how to read in the data, but what do I need to change in the above code to use the columns in my questions? Using Country and Years 2008 to 2011!! To either build the data frame from the file or just use the columns straight away?